# JavaFX write JSON to Rest Service's Outputstram doesn't work

Tags: java, json, rest, javafx

So I have a Rest Service with possibility of adding books. This part looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> addBook(@RequestBody BookTo book) {
    if (!bookService.findBooksById(book.getId()).isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    bookService.saveBook(book);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I wrote JavaFX Rest Service with bookAdd method:

```
@FXML
private void addButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    JSONParserImpl parser = new JSONParserImpl();
    LOG.debug("'Add' button clicked");
    final String targetURL = "http://localhost:8080/webstore/add";
    URL restServiceURL = new URL(targetURL);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) restServiceURL.openConnection();
    httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    String jsonString = parser.toJsonString(model.getTitle(),
            model.getAuthor(),
            model.getStatus().toStatusVO());
    LOG.debug("JSONString: " + jsonString);
    OutputStream output = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
    output.write(jsonString.getBytes());
    output.flush(); 
    LOG.debug("Writing JSON finished.");
}
```

parser method:

```
@Override
public String toJsonString(String title, String author, StatusVO status) {
    LOG.debug("Enter toJsonString method.");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BookVO book = new BookVO(title, author, status);
    String jsonInString = gson.toJson(book);
    LOG.debug("JSONString in method: " + jsonInString);
    return jsonInString;
}
```

BookVO class:

```
public class BookVO {
private Long id;
private String title;
private String authors;
private StatusVO status;
}
```

id is auto generated in rest service.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class BookEntity implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String title;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 200)
private String authors;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BookStatus status;
```

When I click addButton LOG.debug tells me that JSON string looks for example like that:

```
{"title":"bvb","authors":"bvb","status":"FREE"}
```

and if I use for example Postman to add a book with POST and url address: http://localhost:8080/webstore/add and exactly this JSONString as a body, it adds a book properly, but my app doesn't. It shows the last log, but the number of books in service is still the same. What's the problem here?

Comment: Can you explain the issue more clearly? What is the context of your second block of code: is it an event handler in JavaFX (i.e. user presses an "Add" button and this is executed)? And what exactly happens? You say "it adds a book properly" - so that means the server receives the data and successfully persists the book to the backend data, right? What do you mean by "my app doesn't"? If the JavaFX client is not updating, you should post the code that is trying to update the client.

Comment: ok, I've added more content to my question. "it adds a book properly" means that service is written right, but I'm adding a book not via my JavaFX app but using postman: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop . In this chrome add-on I choose POST to address http://localhost:8080/webstore/add and use {"title":"bvb","authors":"bvb","status":"FREE"} as JSON body. And new book appears in service. But when I fire add button in JavaFX I get last log saying "writing JSON finished" but the book isn't added